# Include directory precedence in VS2010

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010

Just installed VS2010 on Windows 7 and am having an issue with include directories while attempting to compile existing C code.  VS2010 appears to search the project directory first for include files regardless whether the `<file.h`> or "file.h" include format is used.  Is there a way to force a different ordering for system include files (`<file.h`>)?  The issue arises because I have name collision between an application header and a system header.

Comment: Praveen:  I added the required system include directory to Project->Properties->ConfigurationProperties->VC/C++Directories->IncludeDirectories but it still searches the project source directory first and gets the wrong header.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit project properties. Check the changes in vs2010 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vsproject/vc-directories).